# Conflict between CSS transition and jQuery fade

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to create a tiled wall with a little menu to `display: none` some elements based on their class. In my CSS I have CSS transitions which are causing `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` to not work. If I add a time, the element will take that long to disappear, but there is no actual fading.

The CSS:

```css
.block:not(.noTransition), .block a img, #main_side p, #main_content, #menu_container{
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The JavaScript using jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').not("#all").click(function(){
        var theId = $(this).attr('id');
        $('.block').not('.'+theId).addClass("noTransition");
        $('.block').not('.'+theId).fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $('.block').not('.'+theId).addClass("covered");
            $('.block').not('.'+theId).removeClass("noTransition");

        });
        $('.'+theId).addClass("noTransition");
        $('.'+theId).fadeIn('slow',function(){
            $('.'+theId).removeClass("covered");
            $('.'+theId).removeClass("noTransition");    
        });
        getScreenSize();
    });
    $("#all").click(function(){
        $('.block').removeClass("covered");
        $('.block').show();
    });
    getScreenSize();
});
```

If I remove the transitions from my CSS the fades do work, but I also want to keep the transitioning to reposition the elements after they have been revealed/hidden.

Comment: I'd try something like this: have your jQuery code add a CSS class (`enable-transitions` or something) to the elements after it's done with them. Attach the CSS transitions to `.block.enable-transitions` etc. (Or vice versa, have jQuery add a class to block transitions when you're fading the element there, and use `:not()` in the CSS, if you want to enable transitions on elements jQuery never works with.)

Comment: Despite having some new different bugs now, it does work! So now I disable the easing while the fading occurs and then after allow easing again. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'd say the cleanest fix for this is to put an extra element around the element that you want to fade. For instance if you're trying to fade this element:

```
<div id="fade"></div>
```

You make the html this:

```
 <div id="fade-parent">
      <div id="fade"></div>
 </div>
```

And then you just fade the parent:

```
 $('#fade-parent').fadeIn();
```

And there's no need for ugly fixes.

Answer (score 3):

I usually do what millimoose suggests:

```
$('#cboxClose').removeClass('transEnabl').fadeIn(500, function() {
  $(this).addClass('transEnabl'); 
});
```

Where *transEnabl* is something like:

```
.transEnabl {
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
```

It is ugly as hell, but it works. The problem comes because css transitions are giving a duration on the execution of the opacity.

Comment: this doesnt work for me, the class is being addes/removed, the transitions are working but the fadein/out still doesnt work.

Comment: When you say "doesn't work" what do you mean? It doesn't trigger? The elements appear all of a sudden, without transition? Please be a little bit more explicit.

Comment: If i remember correctly the problem was that it didnt fadeOut/In smoothly, they just appeared all of a sudden as you said.

Answer (score 0):

In case [Hector's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19675277/573634) doesn't work for you, here's an even uglier solution. (Where we eliminate JQuery's call all together)

Example of fadeOut:

```
$('#test').css('opacity', 0);
window.setTimeout(function() {
     $('#test').remove();
}, $('#test').css('transition-duration').replace('s','')*1000);
```

Essentially we are relying to the CSS transition to do the transition and then we are simply waiting in the JS the duration of the transition as defined by the CSS.