# jQuery fadeOut() skips after CSS fade in

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having a bit of a frustrating problem regarding fading out an element using jQuery after it has been faded in with CSS. I set up a CSS animation to fade in an element when the page loads using the following (I've also got the relevant browser prefixes included too, I'm using Stylus):

```
@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
.elem {
    opacity: 0;
    animation: fadein 500ms ease-in 1ms forwards;
}
```

My issue is that when an event handler is activated that runs the following, the fadeOut does not fade but instead skips straight to nothing:

```
    $('.elem').fadeOut(400, function(){
        $('.elem').fadeIn(400);
    });
```

I've been able to replicate the issue in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gRw7n/2/). Can anyone help me out? :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it's conflicting with the CSS you're using. jQuery is probably using other opacity related properties than what your CSS is. [An all jQuery solution might be this:](http://jsfiddle.net/gRw7n/4/)

CSS

```
.elem {
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('.elem').fadeIn(1000); // on page load, fade in with jQuery

$('#go').click(function(){
    $('.elem').fadeOut(400, function(){
        $('.elem').fadeIn(400);
    });
});
```

Related: [Conflict between CSS transition and jQuery fade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000564/conflict-between-css-transition-and-jquery-fade)

Comment: The solution I ended up using is the one in your related link. Moving the animation details to a different class, adding the class to the element, and then removing the class before fading out seems to work well. I could certainly do it all with jQuery but for now I've already got this CSS animation working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for `FadeIn` and `FadeOut`... here's your code with `animate` and `opacity` instead.

```
$('#go').click(function(){
    $('.elem').css('animation','none').animate({
        'opacity' : 0
        },function(){
            $('.elem').animate({
                'opacity' : 1
                });
        });
    });
```

Comment: This was close. On this initial action the same behavior occurred, but on subsequent actions it faded out properly.

Comment: Of course :) I updated my answer, swapping the opacity values. Just as the author of the correct answer, I would have done it his way although I took for granted you really wanted to use opacity and css animation. Glad you got it to work :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the css-animation has higher precedence than the inline style that jQuery applies to the element when `fadeOut` is used. This means the animation's `opacity : 1;` overrides any opacity setting jQuery applies, up until jQuery sets the element to `display:none;`

You can do this to get around:

```
$('#go').click(function(){

   $('.elem').css('animation','none').fadeOut(400, function(){
      $('.elem').fadeIn(400);
    });

});
```

Comment: This looked promising but didn't seem to work. Blinked away and then never came back.

Comment: Sorry, I missed to add that I had set `.elem { opacity: 1; ... }` in the jsFiddle when playing around. That will make it work as expected. - http://jsfiddle.net/gRw7n/5/