# Conflict between CSS transition-duration and jQuery fade

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, fade

Please see: https://jsfiddle.net/nsx6nvs5/

HTML:

```
<div id="btn"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#btn {
        height: 100px;
        background-color: red;
        transition-duration:1s;
    }

        #btn:hover {
            background-color: green;
        }
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").click(function () {
         $("#btn").fadeOut(2000);
         setTimeout(function () {
             $("#btn").fadeIn(2000);
         }, 3000);
     });
});
```

Fade not work correctly. Why fade and transition-duration have Conflict?

**Note**: Click event is not issue. In other events they have conflict too!

I searched and found that it asked already in other scenario  but not answered as well at all.

[Conflict between CSS transition and jQuery fade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000564/conflict-between-css-transition-and-jquery-fade)

Answer (score 1):

Trying adding this to your #btn CSS:

```
 transition-property: background-color;
```

See Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/apeazzoni/nsx6nvs5/18/

Comment: Thanks and upwote but this isn't my answer. I ask why and don't want code. However this code solve current scenario but in opacity in my main code, this not work (transition-property:opacity;)